# Can create the component but not getting the reference in android 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just updated my android to 3.6.1,  i can add the components like recycleView, TextView and so on but the real problem is when i try to get the reference of it my android doesn't get it and show me an error

Here you go the code

First i create my component

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/RecyclerComments"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="65dp" />
```

Second: I get the reference and to test i try to show it by console.

I declare a variable

```
   RecyclerView recycleComentarios;
```

i take the reference of this textView

```
recycleComentarios = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerComments);
             Log.i("RecycleView ", "Test " + recycleComentarios);
```

This is the output n my console

```
I/RecycleView: Test null
```

and finally the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Anyone has the same error?

Comment: What's `itemView`?

Comment: It's a the View itemView of my Adapter

Comment: Check if you have properly inflated the View (itemView).

Comment: So you have a list of recyclerviews?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was binding the components in a different layout.